# Calling MySql stored function rather than a stored procedure with ADO Command object

Tags: ms-access, vba, ado

I'm trying to call a stored function like this from vba in access:

```
SELECT my_function();
```

If it were a stored procedure it would be like this:

```
CALL my_procedure();
```

For the stored procedure I can use:

```
Dim cmd As Object
Set cmd = CreateObject("ADODB.Command")

With cmd
    Set .ActiveConnection = oConn 'ADODB connection created elsewhere
    .CommandType = adCmdStoredProc
    .CommandText = "my_procedure"
End With

cmd.execute
```

Specifically I'd like to know if there is an equivalent of 'adCmdStoredProc' for functions?

Answer (score 1):

"*Specifically I'd like to know if there is an equivalent of 'adCmdStoredProc' for functions?*"

But the SQL you're using is a SELECT which references a function:

```
SELECT my_function();
```

You have 7 choices from the *CommandTypeEnum*.  *adCmdUnspecified* should work; probably *adCmdUnknown* too.  I would use *adCmdText*, but it's not really "the equivalent of" *adCmdStoredProc* for a function.

```
CommandTypeEnum Constants
Constant         Value  Description
adCmdFile        256    Evaluate as a previously persisted file
adCmdStoredProc    4    Evaluate as a stored procedure
adCmdTable         2    Have the provider generate a SQL query and return all rows from the specified table
adCmdTableDirect 512    Return all rows from the specified table
adCmdText          1    Evaluate as a textual definition
adCmdUnknown       8    The type of the CommandText parameter is unknown
adCmdUnspecified  -1    Default, does not specify how to evaluate
```

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried running it as a `SELECT` statement?

```
SELECT *
FROM my_function()
```

Comment: Yes and that works, but I'd really like to know if there is an equivalent to adCmdStoredProc for functions. Maybe I wasn't clear in that respect.

Comment: I am not aware of an equivalent to adCmdStoredProc for functions.  I always just use a Select to return from a function.